# How to display table row data on modal, after clicking on table button , antg Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog, antd

I have created user Info antd table with 'Edit' button for each user. After clicking n edit modal gets opened and that modal displays form. I want to display that selected user information on modal form. but the not able to display information on modal Please suggest.

versions-("antd": "^4.18.9",
"axios": "^0.26.0",
"react": "^17.0.2",
"react-dom": "^17.0.2",
"react-router-dom": "^6.2.2")

below is my code-

```
import React , {useState , useEffect , useCallback } from 'react'
import Layout, { Header, Content, Footer } from 'antd/lib/layout/layout';
import { Table, Row, Col, Modal, Button, Form } from 'antd';
import axios from 'axios';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import FormBuilder from 'antd-form-builder'


const UsersList = () =>{
    const [data, setdata] = useState([])

    const columns =[
    
        {
            title:'Name',
            dataIndex:'name',
            key:'uname'
    
        },
        {
            title:'Email',
            dataIndex:'emailss',
            key:'uemail'
    
        },
        {
            title:'Address',
            dataIndex:'address',
            key:'uaddress'
    
        },
        {
            title:'Edit User',
            dataIndex:'edit',
            key:'uedit',
            render: (record) =>( <Button type="primary" 
            onClick={showModal}>
                Edit</Button>)
                
        },
    
    ];

    useEffect(() => {
        getData() }
    , [])

    const getData = async () =>{
        const res = await axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`)
        
        setdata(  res.data.map(row =>({id:row.id,name:row.name,emailss:row.email,address:row.address.city,
            addressS:row.address.street,addressSt:row.address.suite,addressZ:row.address.zipcode,
            addressGLn:row.address.geo.lng,addressGLt:row.address.geo.lat})) ); 
            
            
    }

    const [form] = Form.useForm()
    const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false)
    const showModal = useCallback(() => setModalVisible(true), [setModalVisible])
    const hideModal = useCallback(() => setModalVisible(false), [setModalVisible])
    const [personalInfo, setPersonalInfo] = useState({data})
    const [pending, setPending] = useState(false)

 
    const handleFinish = useCallback(values => {
        console.log('Submit: ', values)
        setPending(true)
        setTimeout(() => {
          setPending(false)
          setPersonalInfo(values)
          Modal.success({
            title: 'Success',
            content: 'Infomation updated.',
          })
        }, 1500)
      })


      const meta = {
        disabled: pending,
        initialValues: personalInfo,
        fields: [
                   { key: 'id', label: 'SrNo.' }, 
                   { key: 'name', label: 'Name' },
                   { key: 'emailss', label: 'Email' },
                   { key: 'addressS', label: 'Address:  Street' },
                   { key: 'addressSt', label: 'Address:  Suite' },
                   { key: 'address', label: 'Address:  City' },
                   { key: 'addressZ', label: 'Address:  Zip COde' },
                   { key: 'addressGLt', label: 'Address: Geo:  Latitude' },
                   { key: 'addressGLn', label: 'Address: Geo:  Longitude' }
                ],
      }



    return (
       
        <Layout>
            <Header>Header 1</Header>          
                <Content  style={{padding:50}}>
                    <Row>
                        <Col span={3}/>
                        <Col span={18}>
                            <Table dataSource={data} columns={columns} />
                        </Col>
                        <Col span={3}/>
                    </Row>
                </Content> 

                <Modal title="User Information" closable={!pending} maskClosable={!pending} visible={modalVisible} destroyOnClose
                       onOk={() => form.submit()} onCancel={hideModal} okText={pending ? 'Loading...' : 'Ok'}
                       okButtonProps={{ loading: pending, disabled: pending }} cancelButtonProps={{ disabled: pending }}>

                    <Form form={form} onFinish={handleFinish}>
                        <FormBuilder meta={meta} form={form} />
                    </Form>
                </Modal>           
           <Footer></Footer> 
        </Layout>
        
        );
    


    
}

export default UsersList;
```

Comment: Solution for this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71508124/18200580